# Not displaying data in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, next.js

I'm new in next JS, when I am trying to display my data in a particular route , its not showing , can anyone tell me why its not showing, if you have any query regarding my question please free fell to ask.

[image: Folder Structure]

[image: Output as an Empty Route]

> index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

import { getDataFromSheets} from './libs/sheets'

export default function Home({data}) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Nextsheet </title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Nextsheet </h1>
        <p>Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database</p>
        <ul>
          {data && data.length ? (
            data.map((item) => (
              <li key={item}>
                {item.title} - {item.description} 
              </li>
            ))
          ) : (
            <li>Error: do not forget to setup your env variables </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
// console.log(process.env.NAME);
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
 
  const sheet = await getDataFromSheets();
  return {
    props: {
      data: sheet.slice(0, sheet.length), // remove sheet header
    },
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  };
}
```

> dynamicid.js

```
 import { getDataFromSheets } from "../../libs/sheets"
    
    export default function handler(req, res) {
    
      const { item, description } = getDataFromSheets();
    
      res.status(200).json({ item, description })
      
    }
```

> sheet.js

This is the sheet.js file where i use google api and google sheet id and email that required for making application. GetdataFromSHeet method i called in a index.js file

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function getDataFromSheets() {
  try {
    const target = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
      process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      null,
      (process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_PRIVATE_KEY || '').replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      target
    );

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: jwt });
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: 'sheet'
    });

    
    const rows = response.data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      return rows.map((row) => ({
        title: row[0],
        description: row[1],
      }));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return [];
}
```

Comment: Is `getDataFromSheets()` returning the expected output? Can you share the code for that function? The way you're using it in the `dynamicid.js` API route suggests it returns an object, but you're handling it as an array in the `index.js` page.

Comment: @juliomalves i have updated my code you can checkout now

Comment: @juliomalves i follow your code but still getting an blank json

Comment: you are not calling your api route under dynamicid.js are you? Have you tried to simply debugging it or putting a console.log(data) at the top of your home component to see whats what?

Comment: @Marco can you try to fix my error

Comment: is `getDataFromSheets` synchronous, or asynchronous

Comment: The issue is most likely in your `getDataFromSheets` function. Try debugging that code and see where things aren't going as expected.

Comment: yes brother i will try

Comment: @juliomalves i tried it brother but not working , can you help me to debugging it, let me know what do you from my side